# Store a file inside a jar library

Tags: java, maven, jar, java-11

**How do you store a file inside a jar library?**

**Setup :**
Create a simple maven project with a class that loads something from the resources folder using the getResoruceAsStream() method and a test that runs it. The test will fail with the problem being it couldn't find that file, the same issue will appear later when we try to compile it as a lib and run that class.

**The problem :** Using the only method I know (and the only that you can find on the web) `getResourceAsStream()` will give you a null reference exception, because the file is missing. So how do I add the file to the jar and load it later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the file in the `src/main/resources` directory and use the following method in the class where you need to load that file -

```
private InputStream readFileFromResourcePath(String filename) {
    return getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
}
```

Do not forget to close the stream after consuming it.

Comment: Ah, when porting i forgot that older java versions build with ant didnt have a concept of the resources folder